# Trying to get a Jenkins job to create another job in a view

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Ok so here is my dilemma, I am using some DSL groovy scripting for job creation in Jenkins and have run into a little snag.  I am trying to get Jenkins to create the new job in a folder, in a specific view.  When I run the job initially and it gives me the jobs created, if I click on the link on that page the job looks like it is in the right spot, however, if I go to the view that the job is supposed to be in, that is where I hit my problem, the folder/job isn't there.  It is listed in the all view, but not the one that I want it to be listed in.  Is there a way I can change my script to fix this or is there something in Jenkins that anyone knows about that will fix this?  Any help would be awesome!

older { name "${project}" } job { name "${project}/${project}Web" } folder { name "${project}" } job { name "${project}/${project}Web" }

This is the part of the code we are using to make the folder.

Comment: it might help, if you would add the code you are using and e.g. examples of the URLs.

Comment: please edit the question.  comments are for comments.  those infos are vital for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This DSL will put your project into a new view - not sure about the folder part though...

```
jenkins = Hudson.instance

job = jenkins.getView("All").getItem(yourJobName);
jenkins.getView("yourNewView").add(job);
```

Answer (score 0):

for current jenkins installations using this code:

`import jenkins.model.Jenkins
job = jenkins.instance.getView("All").getItem(yourJobName);
Jenkins.instance.getView("MyView").add(job);`